# How to apply json ignore annotation on a rest controller method endpoint in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a class called Customer

```
Customer{
   private int ID;
   private IDCard idCard;
}
```

and IDCard.Java

```
IDCard{
   private int id;
   private int score;
}
```

I have two endpoints, endpoint01 and endpoint02.
So when I add a customer using endpoint01, providing score is mandatory. But when I add customer using endpoint02, score is not mandatory.

As I am using Same customer model in both endpoint's controller method, Jackson throws error because on endpoint02 I didn't provide score.
In this case its clear that I can not apply json ignore in my IDCard model. So how can I tell my endpoint02 to ignore score field if it is not present and deserialize only if the field is present in the json object.

This is my endpoint02

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/add",headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody Map<String,List<String>> add(@RequestBody Customer customer)  {
    return customerSvc.add(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is annotation on your POJO and not on your ENDPOINT

```
IDCard{

   @JsonProperty(vaue="id" , required=false)
   private int id;
   @JsonProperty(vaue="score" , required=false)
   private int score;

}
```

this will enable your fields to be avoided while deserializing the object.

Note : take care of encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply ignore annotation on the specific property.